# Module jupyter-vuetify semver range is not registered as a widget module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, vuetify.js, jupyter-lab

(Python 3.8.6)

I am unable to get vuetify widgets running on jupyter lab running in docker container.

I am simply trying to run this sample code after installing ipyveutify:

```py
import ipyvuetify as v
 
my_select = v.Select(
    label='Fruits',
    items=['Apple', 'Pear', 'Cherry']) my_select
```

I keep getting the error:

> Error displaying widget: model not found

Console log:

```sh
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module jupyter-vuetify, semver range
^1.6.1 is not registered as a widget module
     at WidgetManager.loadClass (vendors~main.b94fae9511677b724926.js:664506)
     at WidgetManager.<anonymous> (vendors~main.b94fae9511677b724926.js:719882)
     at step (vendors~main.b94fae9511677b724926.js:719663)
     at Object.next (vendors~main.b94fae9511677b724926.js:719644)
     at vendors~main.b94fae9511677b724926.js:719638
     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
     at push.hs2k.__awaiter (vendors~main.b94fae9511677b724926.js:719634)
     at WidgetManager.push.hs2k.ManagerBase._make_model (vendors~main.b94fae9511677b724926.js:719876)
     at WidgetManager.<anonymous> (vendors~main.b94fae9511677b724926.js:719865)
     at step (vendors~main.b94fae9511677b724926.js:719663)
```

I have done:

```sh
$ conda install -c conda-forge ipyvuetify 
$ jupyter labextension install jupyter-vuetify
$ jupyter lab clean && jupyter lab build
bash-4.2$ jupyter labextension list 
 
> JupyterLab v2.2.9 Known
> 
> labextensions:    app dir: /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
>         @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v2.0.0  enabled  OK
>         @jupyterlab/git v0.23.2  enabled  OK
>         @jupyterlab/toc v4.0.0  enabled  OK
>         @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition v1.0.0  enabled  OK
>         @ryantam626/jupyterlab_code_formatter v1.3.8  enabled  OK
>         bqplot v0.5.20  enabled  OK
>         jupyter-leaflet v0.13.5  enabled  OK
>         jupyter-vue v1.5.0  enabled  OK
>         jupyter-vuetify v1.6.1  enabled  OK
>         jupyterlab-drawio v0.7.0  enabled  OK
>         jupyterlab-plotly v4.14.3  enabled  OK
>         jupyterlab_templates v0.2.5  enabled  OK
>         nbdime-jupyterlab v2.0.1  enabled  OK
>         qgrid2 v1.1.3  enabled  OK*
```

```
bash-4.2$ conda list | grep vue  
> ipyvue                   1.5.0       pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
> ipyvuetify               1.6.1       pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Can you test it in a jupyter Notebook as well ? (I know that it is not you intention but if it doesn't work then the problem lies deeper)

Answer (score 2):

When the base conda env had ipyvuetify already installed in it. Then I ran the notebook on jupyterlab, ipyvuetify had no trouble executing properly!